# How can I solve this problem using snake lemma?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, exact-sequence

I have the following situation:

> [image]
>
> I have this commutative diagram of $R$-modules and homomorphisms such that each row is exact. First I want to show that if $f$ and $h$ are monomorphisms then $g$ is a monomorphism.

To do so I wanted to show that $\ker(g)=\{0\}$ since we just know that $g$ is a homomorphism. Therefore I took $x\in \ker(g)$,  so $g(x)=0_N$. But since the rows are exact I know that $N'\rightarrow N$ needs to be injective. So $\bar u(0)=0_N=g(x)$ (I denote now $u$ tilde as $\bar u$). But then I don't see where to continue, could maybe someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x\in\ker(g)$, so $g(x)=0$. Then, $h\circ v(x)=\tilde v\circ g(x)=0$, so $v(x)\in\ker(h)$. But since $h$ is injective, $v(x)=0$, so $x\in\ker(v)=\mathrm{im}(u)$. Let $x=u(y)$ for some $y\in M'$. Then, $\tilde u\circ f(y)=g\circ u(y)=g(x)=0$, so since both $\tilde u$ and $f$ are injective, we have $y=0$.

Thus, $x=u(y)=0$.

Comment: Oh wow perfect thanks! Would you mind if I try to prove the same statement with surjectivity and then put my work here to see if it is correct? So that you can take a look at it?

Comment: Sure! Although it also follows from formal considerations by looking at the dual category (which is also abelian.)

Comment: Hmm so I wanted to work with the cokernel is this not possible? Because we haven't talked about the dual category

Comment: Is it correct that if I take $\bar x\in coker(g)$ then $\bar x=x+im(g)$

Comment: You should take an arbitrary element $x\in N$ and try to prove it is in the image of $g$ by chasing the diagram, just like what I have done.

Comment: Ah okey so I need to find $m\in M$ such that $g(m)=x$.

Comment: sorry to disturb again. I have some problems since I have never used that $f$ is surjective but I don't find my mistake. Let $n\in N$. Then I know that $im(\bar v)=\ker(\bar u)=0$ hence $\bar v(n)=0$ Since $h$ is surjective there exists $m''\in M''$ such that $h(m'')=0=\bar v(n)$. Now we also know that $im(v)=M''$ hence there exists $m\in M$ such that $v(m)=m''$ thus $$h(m'')=h(v(m))=\bar v(n)$$ But we also have $h(v(m))=\bar v(g(m))$. Can I then deduce that $g(m)=n$? And if not is it correct till now?

Comment: How do you know $im(\tilde v)=0$?? That $\tilde v(n)=0$ is certainly not true in general.

Comment: Ohhh noo i thought $im(\bar v )=\ker(\bar u)$ but it's the other way round

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136860/discussion-between-kenta-s-and-wave).